# Transferring data from one open workbook to another open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two open workbooks, Workbook A and Workbook B .I have columns of data that I need to transfer from a specific sheet from Workbook A to a specific sheet in Workbook B.

Sample data:

```
-26.32
-20.56
-44.93
-26.64
-45.99
-40.76
-34.21
-25.54
-48.63    
2.966    
9.163    
4.879    
5.01    
11.48    
16.19    
16.19
```

How to create a program that transfers this from Workbook A to Workbook B? Also Workbook A can be any open workbook. It might not be the same file when this program runs again. Thanks in advance.

**Current Code:**

```
Sub Sample()

Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
Dim filepath As String

Set wbA = ThisWorkbook 'you say the current workbook
filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , , , False)

Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

With wbA
    .Sheets("Results").Range("A1").Copy wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
End With

End Sub
```

Choose Source and Destination Workbook:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim wbA As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
Dim filepath As String

filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , , , False)
Set wbA = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , , , False)
Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

With wbA
    .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3").Copy wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: many missing bits of information here. but i posted a generic answer anyways. I don't kwow `Created by my program and not saved` how are you doing this? so i did not include it in the code. perhaps you can elaborate how you choose the unsaved WB? do you open it or simply add a new one?

Comment: This question is a part of a bigger program. The Workbook A is already created by the program, i've done that part already. I just need a way to copy and paste data between the two workbooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Sub Sample()

 Dim wbA as  Workbook, wbB as Workbook
 Dim filepath as String

 Set wbA = Thisworkbook 'you say the current workbook
 filepath = "C:\User\UserName\Documents\Myworkbook.xlsx" 'hard coded version

 Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

With wbB
    .Sheets("your sheet name here").Range("your range here").Copy _
    wbA.Sheets("destination sheet here").Range("destination range here")
End With

End Sub
```

If however you want to select your file, use this line:

```
filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), "*.xlsx",,,,False) 'open file dialog version
```

Then you got to select the file from the location.
Hope this helps a bit.

**Edit1:** Try this

```
filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), "*.xlsx") 'open file dialog version
```

Comment: Source wb is already created, i'm just not so sure on how set it in wbA

Comment: how do you create it? is it temporary? or do you open it somewhere else? i need to know so i can help you `Setting` it.

Comment: Workbook A is the current workbook. Workbook B is a pre-made file that i already have, I didnt make it, it's downloaded.

Comment: so it is downloaded and saved in a location? or email?

Comment: It's downloaded and saved in a location

Comment: The second way, where you can select your file, it returns compile error when i run it.

Comment: It's still the same, it says Expected: list separator or ). Also, i'm using excel 2007, could this be a problem?

Comment: no not really. how about this `filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", , , , False)`

Comment: I'm trying to copy only one cell, it says subscript our of range. Why is that?      .Sheets(Results).Range("A1").Copy _ wbB.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A1")

Comment: enclose sheet name in `""` like this: `.Sheets("Results").Range("A1").Copy _ wbB.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`.

Comment: I did that, it still gives the same "subscript out of range" error. Am I doing something wrong? I have both the workbooks open, and i run this program. I've added the code to the edit for you to have a look.

Comment: your code is ok but does all those sheets exist? also see your code, i updated it doing the copy in one line removing `_`. Aslo make sure that `wbA` and `wbB` don't interchange. what you're code does is that it copies from sheet named `Result` from your current workbook to `Sheet1` of your newly opened workbook. is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The sheets exist, i've checked, but i still get the subscript out of range error :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45339/discussion-between-l42-and-user3163920)

Comment: Hello again, i was just wondering if i can also select the source workbook just like how i can choose the destination workbook? I've added the code i've tried. It doesn't work

Comment: I didn't follow. you mean from another open workbook?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to have the freedom to do this transfer between any two open workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

Way late on this conversation.  I know that.  But..... It seems like he's asking how to send data from one open workbook to another open workbook. All the answers above include code for him to "open" the workbook.  So I understand where the confusion came from.  The workbook is already open.  Trying to open it again will cause an error message.

For anyone seeking this same advice in the future - to reference an already-open workbook you only need to use it's name and extension as such: WorkBooks("openWorkBookName.xlsx")

There is no need to reference the file's folder or directory location.

```
Sub setVariableToAnotherALREADYopenWB()
        Dim anotherOpenWorkbook     As Workbook
        Dim ws2                     As Worksheet
    
    '   The Full File Location/Folder/Directory is not necessary
    '   when referring to another open workbook
    '
    '   Just use the name of the workbook and it's extension
    
        Set anotherOpenWorkbook = Workbooks("Phone Dir.xlsx")
        Set ws2 = anotherOpenWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Office Phone Directory").Range("A12:A39").Copy _
                    Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
    
    
    
    
    Set anotherOpenWorkbook = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    End Sub
```